# How to cut out a scope using "even odd rule"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a predefined geometry \big_area and want to fill it out cutting another predefined piece \cut_this_out from it. And I want to cut a whole "scope" from it and not an explicit definition of a shape.

```
\def \cutout {(0,0) --++ (3.5,0) --++ (0,7) --++ (-3.5,0) --++(0,-7)}

\def \mycircle {(0,0) circle (10)}


\begin{tikzpicture}


%This works
\fill[even odd rule] \mycircle \cutout;

%This doesn't work
%\fill[even odd rule] \mycircle \begin{scope}[xshift=1cm] \cutout \end{scope};


\end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: 'And' we want a complete minimal working example. :)

Comment: That may be what you want but I strongly suspect that you cannot have it. A complete minimal example might enable somebody to suggest an alternative. Without that, I doubt anybody can be of much help.

Comment: I added a working minimal code

Comment: That's not a minimal example. Please provide a minimal example which can be used to reproduce the problem you want help with i.e. copy-paste-compile and get a problem to work on. Your code will not compile, so cannot possibly count as a suitable minimal example. (Nor will it produce an error you are asking about when an attempt is made to compile it.)

Comment: Well, I guess you ***can*** put a scope in the middle of a path, after all. I didn't realise that `\draw[fill, even odd rule] (0,0) circle (3) {[shift={(1cm,1cm)}](0,0) circle (1)};` would work. Interesting. But then I don't see why this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need the scopes library in that case. `\draw[fill, even odd rule] (0,0) circle (3) [shift={(1cm,1cm)}](0,0) circle (1);` will work. But you do need it for the more complex cases.

Answer (score 4):

One option with `scopes` library

```
%\usetikzlibrary{scopes} %<---- Somewhere in the preamble

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\big_area{(0,0) circle (3)}
\def\cut_this_out{(0,0) circle (1)}
%\draw[fill, even odd rule] \big_area \cut_this_out;

\draw[fill, even odd rule] \big_area {[shift={(3cm,2cm)}]\cut_this_out};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

For your own sanity, don't use underscores in TeX macro names.

Comment: you mean \draw[fill, even odd rule] \big_area [shift={(3cm,2cm)}]\cut_this_out};

Comment: Still I don't love this solution...I want to make another stuff with it. Scale..anchor..styles...I would love to have a fully working scope..

Comment: @Caniko No brace starts before `[shift...` and if you don't ask what you want you don't get it. Not my problem what you love.

Comment: I clearly asked to cut a whole "scope". and not to shift anything. What you suggested is a workaround for my minimal example. But the question is clearly asked I think. I upvoted your post. But it's not the solution I imagine. If there's no solution the way I imagine, it's absolutely ok.

Comment: @Caniko Which exactly does that. Did you add the scopes library and compiled what I wrote? You changed your question with the shift. I don't get what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you just do this? That is, why do you need a scope at all? It certainly isn't required for the examples you've given.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill, even odd rule] (0,0) circle (3) [shift={(1cm,1cm)}](0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\def \cutout {(0,0) --++ (3.5,0) --++ (0,7) --++ (-3.5,0) --++(0,-7)}
\def \mycircle {(0,0) circle (10)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[even odd rule] \mycircle [xshift=1cm]\cutout;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: cut out circle]

[image: cut out rectangle]

Comment: @CroCo I don't think it is originally. I think I copied it from the question ;).